# IIS7 URL rewriter, create a friendly url for a PDF

Tags: url, iis-7

I installed and setup IIS7 URL Rewrite.
My goal was to redirect from the following:
           www.mydomain.com/ELMWSA/waterquality
to
           www.mydomain.com/portals/0/pdf/CCR2012.pdf

The following is the rule added to my web.config

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WaterQuality">
                <match url="/ELMWSA/WaterQuality$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/portals/0/pdf/CCR2012.pdf" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

For reasons I don't see, it has no affect.  I am not redirected to the PDF docuemnt.
I have also tried with the action "redirect", and I have tested the incoming URL and it passed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL rewrite applies to URLs coming *in* to the server *from* the client. It does not rewrite anything you put on the page. Simply change the URL on the page yourself.

Edit: further to your comment, I got it to work on a test site with

```
<rewrite>                                                                                      
    <rules>                                                                                    
        <rule name="WaterQuality" stopProcessing="true">                                       
            <match url="ELMWSA/WaterQuality$" />                                                
            <action type="Rewrite" url="portals/0/pdf/CCR2012.pdf" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>                                                                                
    </rules>                                                                                   
</rewrite>
```

You might want to edit the URL Rewrite rules in IIS Manager to show you all the options available in a rewrite rule.

Comment: Let me rephrase.  I need to redirect to the pdf document when someone enters the url: www.mydomain.com/ELMWSA/waterquality.  When I type the URL shown, I am not redirected to the Document.

Comment: Andrew you completely Rock.  Thanks very much.